# How to make other images display on list in Android list

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm calling a custom list named list_item from main.java but when it loads on the emulator it shows same image for rest of the items.

Code of main.java:

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.id.textView1,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names)));
}

private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] strings) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) row.findViewById (R.id.imageView1);
        TextView tv = (TextView)  row.findViewById (R.id.textView1);

        tv.setText(items[position]);
        if (items[position].equals("rahman")) {
            iv.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.rahman_two);
}
        else if (items[position].equals("raheem")) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.rahim_three);
}
        else if (items[position].equals("malik")) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.malik_four);
}
        else if (items[position].equals("quddus")) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.quddus_five);
}

        return row;
    }


}
```

Comment: i believe this code snippet is from getView function. right?

Comment: @Farhan yes it is from getView function.

Answer (score 0):

What is `position` in this case? Are you Looping through items?
If that is the case, then ImageView should show the image corresponding to the last element in  items.

@Techno23 Are you trying to do something like: `tv.getText().toString.equals("rahman");`

Comment: It is not showing the corresponding image rather it is just showing ic_launcher with all the items.

Comment: I am trying this instead:

tv.setText(items[position]);
   if (items[position].equals("rahman")) {
       iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.rahman_two);

Comment: I tried using @android:drawable/ as the source but it is not acceptable by the ADT :/

Comment: @Techno23 Do you mind posting the whole code for this function

Comment: public class Main extends ListActivity {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
 setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.id.textView1,
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
 getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names)));
 }
 
 private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

  public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
    String[] strings) {
   super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
   // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

Comment: @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
   String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names);
   
   ImageView iv = (ImageView) row.findViewById (R.id.imageView1);
   TextView tv = (TextView)  row.findViewById (R.id.textView1);

Comment: I have edited my question and have added the whole code you asked for.

Comment: @Techno23 Not sure. You can check if the hardcoded strings match with the values in strings.xml